# How to send ArrayList into BaseAdapter Android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, baseadapter

I want to display my JSON into gridview, before it.. i displayed my JSON into ListView, and it works. but in BaseAdapter, i don't know how to send my JSON that I have put into ArrayList into Base Adapter

so this is my source code :

Activity :

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    List AgenList = new ArrayList();
        boolean boolStatusKoneksi=true;
        private ProgressDialog Dialog;
        protected Context applicationContext;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            new AgenAsyncTask().execute();
            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new AgenAdapter(this));
        }


    public class AgenAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            Dialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu sebentar...");
            Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            Dialog.setCancelable(true);
            Dialog.show();
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                 String url = ("http:10.10.2/selectAgent.htm");

                  try{
                      JSONParser j=new JSONParser();
                        JSONArray jsonArray = j.takeJson(url);;

                      for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                          JSONObject c  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            if (c.has("atasan")) 
                                map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
                            if (c.has("nama_agen")) 
                                map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());
                            if (c.has("kode_agen")) 
                                map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());
                            if (c.has("no_aaji")) 
                                map.put("no_aaji", c.get("no_aaji").toString());
                            if (c.has("jenis")) 
                                map.put("jenis", c.get("jenis").toString());
                              AgenList.add(map);
                         }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                  return null;
                    }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

       }
   }
```

This is my BaseAdapter :

```
    public class AgenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public AgenAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater layout = getLayoutInflater();
            View view= layout.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

            TextView ATASAN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.atasan);
            TextView NAMA_AGEN= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_agen);
            TextView KODE_AGEN= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kode_agen);
            TextView NO_AAJI= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_aaji);
            TextView JENIS= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jenis);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see, i have ArrayList named as = AgenList but i haven't put it into my BaseAdapter.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a parametrized constructor and pass your array list into its paramerts. so your class will be like

```
public class AgenAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<yourObj> list;
Activity a;
    public AgenAdapter(Activity activity,List<yourObj> list) {
       this.a=activity;
       this.list=list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();///////return size of list
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;///// dont return null here
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;/////////return position as itemID
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layout = getLayoutInflater();
        View view= layout.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

        TextView ATASAN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.atasan);
        TextView NAMA_AGEN= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_agen);
        TextView KODE_AGEN= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kode_agen);
        TextView NO_AAJI= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_aaji);
        TextView JENIS= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jenis);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work all that i need is how to put my arraylist that containing my JsonArray

Comment: if you want to send any data into your adapter, you will have to use the same technique, sent your data using parametrized constructor of your adapter class, in case of JSONArray your method will be like:

JSONArray list;
Activity a;
    public AgenAdapter(Activity activity,JSONArray list) {
       this.a=activity;
       this.list=list;

    }

Comment: made some changes, see code above and look for comments added in it

Comment: still force close, this is what log cat say Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: its because you're extending your class with`ListActivity` than Activity, you must have a `ListView` in your layout xml file, with the id, `@android:id/list`. extending `ListActivity` means that this activity, mainly is a list, but may have some components beside it. so, when you assume an activity is a list originally, you should have specify a list inside layout xml file of that acitivty, that is the main list. that list, should have the id, `@android:id/list`. so, simply set id field of the `ListView` of your activity, to `@android:id/list`.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
gridview.setAdapter(new AgenAdapter(this), AgenList);
```

and use this line in your onPostExecute()  instead of onCreate()

Like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
     gridview.setAdapter(new AgenAdapter(this), AgenList);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). It contains all of the implementation for an Adapter based on an [`ArrayList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

1. Make your adapter a subclass of [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), giving a parametrised type. Yours in this case being `Map<String, String>`

   ```
   public class ResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map<String,String>> {

       private int mResource;

       /**
       * @param context
       * @param resource
       */
       public ResultAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Map<String,String>> dataList) {
           super(context, resource, dataList);
           this.mResource = resource;
       }

       ...

   }
   ```
2. Override the [getView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method of the ArrayAdapter to use to set the data given to the views.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view;
       // If the view is already inflated, reuse it.
       // Else inflate the view
       if (convertView != null) {
           view = convertView;
       } else {
           //inflate view
           final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           view = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
       }

       TextView ATASAN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.atasan);
       ...


       //Get data here
       Map<String, String> item = getItem(position);

       //Set data to the View's e.g.
       ATASAN.setText(item.get("ATASAN"));
       ...

       return view;
   }
   ```